# How to dump/log default values that are passed to hooks/filter functions?

Tags: debug, logging

Here's a quick example of I am trying to achieve:

**I am using this filter:**

```
add_filter('manage_edit-member_columns', 'set_custom_edit_member_columns');

function set_custom_edit_member_columns($columns) {

    $columns['photo'] = "Photo";

    return $columns;

}
```

The function has one parameter passed ($columns). I want to see what's inside of $columns. By the example in the codex, I know it's an array with column names.

Question... how can I dump/log the values of in that array?

I am using Chrome. So I installed Chromelogger. This will let me log arrays, but it does not seem to work when it's called inside the function set_custom_edit_member_columns(). Thus, I can't get the values of $columns.

This is just an example. But, pretty much I am struggling to find a way to dump variables that are used inside functions.php or other php files that do not directly print to the page I am currently viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your log on the server, try using php's [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) which is more flexible than just writing to files on disk. Something along the lines of:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-member_columns', 'set_custom_edit_member_columns');

function set_custom_edit_member_columns($columns) {

    error_log(print_r($columns,true),3,__DIR__."/log.txt");

    $columns['photo'] = "Photo";

    return $columns;

}
```

OTOH, if you find the browser console more convenient, you should include a js script to [`console.log()`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) your data. Like so:

```
$log_msgs=array();

add_filter('manage_edit-member_columns', 'set_custom_edit_member_columns');

function set_custom_edit_member_columns($columns) {
    global $log_msgs;

    $log_msgs[]=json_encode($columns);

    $columns['photo'] = "Photo";

    return $columns;

}

function console_log_msgs()
  {
  global $log_msgs;
  foreach($log_msgs as $msg)
    echo "<script>console.log($msg);</script>";
  }

add_action('wp_footer','console_log_msgs');
```

*(didn't test the above code, but you get the idea)*

Comment: This worked great. Thank you very much. The file saved right away with the array in it.

Answer (score 1):

When a [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php) or any other screen output is not posible, you can use [error_log](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php). The message will be added to the error_log file on your server. To log variables I like [this small function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress):

```
function log_it( $message ) {
   if( WP_DEBUG === true ){
     if( is_array( $message ) || is_object( $message ) ){
       //error_log will be located according to server configuration
       //you can specify a custom location if needed like this
       //error_log( $var, 0, "full-path-to/error_log.txt")
       error_log( print_r( $message, true ) );
     } else {
       error_log( $message );
     }
   }
}
```

To use use it, [turn WP_DEBUG on](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and do someting like this:

```
function set_custom_edit_member_columns($columns) {

    log_it( $columns );

    $columns['photo'] = "Photo";

    return $columns;

}
```

Comment: Everything you answer makes perfect sense, and yet I can't get it to work. I cannot even get a simple log_it("test"). I have WP_DEBUG ON. I know because I see all notices on the home page. Anything that could prevent the log from being created?

Comment: Are you sure? Can you ask to your hosting support the location of the `error_log` file? Maybe you don't see it. Also, you can try just `error_log("test")`; [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) is a native PHP function, nothing to do with WordPress; if it doesn't work you will need to contact with the hosting support, there is nothing we can do then.

Comment: I've read the other answer and you said that it works. So, I confirm that my answer doesn't work for you because you didn't find the error_log file; the other answer use error_log like me but specifying a custom path for the generated file.

Comment: I know cybmeta. It must be a server setting. I found two log files. One in the site root and one and the theme root. Neither one had the errors logged.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following function in your `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_178547_log( $message ) {
    file_put_contents( 'custom.log', date( "d-m-Y H:i:s" ) . ' ::::: ' . $message . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
}
```

Then:

```
function set_custom_edit_member_columns($columns) {

    wpse_178547_log('$columns');

    foreach($columns as $column){
        wpse_178547_log($column);
    }

    $columns['photo'] = "Photo";

    return $columns;

}
```

A file named `custom.log` will be created in project's root.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using file_put_contents but that option is typically turned off by default on most servers. Unfortunately some servers won't let you edit php.ini.